# Using radio button with Rail 5.1.6 & Bootstrap 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I m trying to implement a simple radio button with rails 5.1.6.  I will be very pleased if anybody can help there.

The form seem to work, not error returned but the value stored is unexpected (value stored is):   {:id=>"project_type", :checked=>"review", :class=>"w-form-control"}

i m using:

```
<%= form_with @project do |f| %>
   <h4 class="info-text"> (...some text...) </h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="<%= I18n.t(".project_create-teaser1") %>">
       <%= f.radio_button :project_type, id: "project_type", ['some value'] %>
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-building"></i>
              </div>
       ... code continues...
```

Comment: `form_with` expects a `model:` attribute in order to behave the way you want. Does changing your first line to `form_with model: @project do |f|` help?

Comment: @Scott:  the for_with is a typo. I tried using form_with but reverted back to form_for.  I retried the _with syntax without luck

Comment: @Kedarnag: the suggestion u made is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> radio_button(object_name, method, tag_value, options = {})

You have to send the arguments in the correct order for the `radio_button` to work correctly. The below code should fix the problem

```
<%= f.radio_button :project_type, ['some value'], id: "project_type" %>
```

The above will generate the below *HTML*

```
=> "<input id=\"project_type\" type=\"radio\" value=\"some value\" name=\"project[project_type]\" />"
```

which is correct

Comment: Hi Pavan,  thanks for the response but that does not work.

Comment: @Thierry Can you paste the html for the `radio_tag` that you see in the browser console?

Comment: User Load (3.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Project Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "Projects".* FROM "Projects" WHERE "Projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/Projects/2/setup
Completed 302 Found in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)

Comment: @Thierry No, not that. Open the bowser, right click on the radio button, click on inspect element. It will open the console in the bowser. You will see the HTML code. Look for the radio button code, copy and paste it here.

Comment: I retrieve this:   
<input type="radio" value="project" name="project[project_type]" id="project_project_type_protype" checked="checked">

Comment: Looks good. Did you checked the value that is getting stored now?

Comment: yes, the issue lies in the form itself.  I m trying to build a stepped filing process that involves 5 tabs.  When I m reducing the length/simplifying the form then it works. I probably need to let rails knows when the action button ends or something like that.  I m exploring wrapping the actions inside a form tag.